# FileSystemResource to MultipartFile

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, file, templates

I want to send my image from my storage using the path like this:

```
MultiValueMap<String, Object> image = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>(); 
image.add("image", new FileSystemResource("C:\\xx\\xx\\xx\\xx\\xx\\xx\\xx\\img\\xx.jpg"));
```

so I call the object using the code below:

```
MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String,Object>();
body.add("image", image);
```

Then, I get this error:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap["image"]->java.util.LinkedList[0]->org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource["inputStream"])] with root cause

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap["image"]->java.util.LinkedList[0]->org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource["inputStream"])
```

I am using the Rest Template of spring boot, which requires me to send by POST Method the `MultipartFile` object. Now, I do not know how to convert into the `MultipartFile` type,
 so the Rest Template can accept my request post.

Note: I want to use the `body.add("image", image.getResource());` but It did not show up in selection since image wasn't of `MultipartFile` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
    @GetMapping(path = "/copy", produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> copyFile() {

        MultiValueMap<String, Object> body
                = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        body.add("image", new FileSystemResource("test.jpg"));

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity
                = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);

        String serverUrl = "http://localhost:8080/upload";

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate
                .postForEntity(serverUrl, requestEntity, String.class);

        return response;
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "/upload", produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
    public String uploadFile(@RequestParam("image") MultipartFile file) {

        try {

            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
            Path path = Paths.get("./uploadedImages/" + file.getOriginalFilename());
            Files.write(path, bytes);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Error";
        }

        return "File Uploaded";
    }
```